# get navigationItem from by custom UINavigationBar class

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

To customize my navigation bar, I did several steps:

1. create a subclass which inheriting from `UINavigationBar` class, do some customization like draw shadow or setting background image for the navigation bar.
2. create an empty xib file, which contains nothing but a navigation view controller.
3. set the class name for the navigation bar in the navigation view controller.

Everything works fine, but when I want to add another customized back button on the navigation bar, I tried to attach a `UIBarButtonItem` to the `navigationItem.backbarbuttonitem`, I have no idea how to get the `navigationItem` from the `UINavigationBar` subclass.

code sample:

```
// header file
@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end

// implementation file
@implementation MyNavigationBar
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  // background image
  UIImage* background_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-navigation-bar.png"];
  [self setBackgroundImage:background_image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  // draw shadow
  self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
  self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
  self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
}

@end
```

Is there any way to get the `navigationItem` entry in my customized `UINavigationBar` subclass, or I just did it the wrong way? :P

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the uinavigationbar. then put a uiview which can have height and width of uinavigationbar. and then add as many as buttons can fit or you want. add uiimage to the view. you will have a nice customized uinavigation bar. you can mimic the back button by using popviewcontroller or poptorootviewcontroller.